# Setting WebView initial zoom out to a particular value

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I had added a few images in webview and also have the zooming feature. but initially the webview is so small that a person cannot read the data of the images until he zooms to read it. so I just want to know how can I set webview initial zoom feature to a particular value

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.phy_law_web);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mathscribe/Analyticgeometry.html");
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```